# Verilog: Pass a vector as a port to a module

Tags: fpga, lcd, verilog, xilinx, spartan

I have two modules

1. counter: Output is a vector called error_count.
2. lcd: Module to display the code on an LCD. Input includes clock and error_count.

Following snippet of the code is most relevant and attached below:

1. Top level module:

   ```
   counter counter1 (..., error_count);
   lcd lcd1 (..., error_count);
   ```
2. counter module:

   ```
   module counter (..., error_count);
   ...
   output reg [31:0] error_count = 0;
   ... //Update counter every clock cycle
   endmodule
   ```
3. lcd module:

   ```
   module lcd (..., error_count);
   ...
   input [31:0] error_count;
   ... //error_count used to display on LCD
   endmodule
   ```

What is wrong with this code? The display just prints 0 as the output. Is there anything wrong with the way I am passing the the vector?

Additional Info:
I am using the Xilinx Spartan 3E starter kit for testing this code. The LCD code is fine and I have tested it with local counter (which was reg[31:0]).

Comment: Sharing more of your code will get you better answers. There's nothing in your snippets that looks like a problem, but there's a hundred ways you could have a problem in code you haven't shared.

Answer (score 2):

The code you showed has a few problems:

- You don't show how `error_count` is declared in the top-level module. If `error_count` is just declared as `wire error_count;`, you only have a single bit of your counter connected between the counter module and the lcd module.
- You don't show how the counter is updated in the counter module. You could have a bug there that results in the counter never updating. Since it is initialized to 0, you'd always have a 0 output from the counter module.
- You don't show any clock input to the counter module. If clock is not connected, error_counter will never be updated.
- You say that lcd has a clock input, but you don't show that it actually does, and you don't show any code where it matters.
- You don't show how your clock is generated. If there's no clock, the counter won't updated.
- You don't show the complete input and output ports to either module. With your coding style it's easy to connect a wrong input to a wrong port. I much prefer to intantiate modules with the syntax like

  `counter counter1 ( .clk( clock )  , .error_count( error_count ) );`

  With this style, the order of naming the in's and out's in the instantiation doesn't matter.
- You haven't shown any reset signal, but you probably have one. If the reset is stuck in the active state, probably the error_count won't ever increment.

Comment: wire error_count was the mistake